# THREE.js Texture Flickers

Tags: three.js

Take a look at http://www.benmarshall.me/projects/playground/072012/solar-system.html. Notice as the earth rotates, one of the textures either the cloud or earth flickers. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both spheres have the same size you'll run into z buffer issues. Basically the graphics card doesn't know what's closer to the camera and sometimes one sphere is closer than the other and alternates.